# React Native MaskedView for Android

Tags: react-native, view, mask

React Native has built-in `MaskedViewIOS` which is for ios, and it's working great. I would like to know if there's also something similar for android. Looking on the source of React Native, there's a built-in component which is named `MaskedView` only, which - I suspect - should work for both platforms (iOS and Android). However, trying to use it the same way as `MaskedViewIOS`, some error occurs.

P.S. I haven't used `MaskedView` on Android yet (since it broke on iOS)

P.P.S `MaskedView` is `underfined`, so I guess it is not currently support on Android. Any 3rd library open source perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the MaskedViewIOS usage scenarios can be covered with my [react-native-image-filter-kit](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) library. "Image behind text" example from RN [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/maskedviewios#docsNav):

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { DstATopComposition, TextImage } from 'react-native-image-filter-kit'

const masked = (
  <DstATopComposition
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    resizeCanvasTo={'dstImage'}
    dstImage={
      <Image
        style={{ width: 320, height: 320 }}
        source={{ uri: 'https://una.im/CSSgram/img/cacti.jpg' }}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      />
    }
    srcImage={
      <TextImage
        fontName={'Gagarin'}
        text={'basic mask'}
        fontSize={80}
      />
    }
  />
)
```

Android:

[image: Android]

iOS:

[image: iOS]

P.S. Gagarin font was taken from [here](https://www.1001freefonts.com/gagarin.font) and renamed to 'Gagarin.ttf'